# Any way to program the Lego NXT brick in Assembly Language?

Tags: assembly, nxt, lego-mindstorms

The question says it all. Im currently learning assembly and thought it would be fun to program my nxt in assembly language to get practice at the language. And so I was wondering whether it is possible for this to be done.

Thanks
-Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**

The only example I know to actually use assembly as the programming language would be *"NBC"*. For details on NBC, check the BricxCC website at sourceforge (http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/nbc/).